# Square root of a natural number to square root of another natural number

Tags: number-theory, roots

Is there such integers $x,y$ which they're not perfect squares and they're not equal, such that:

$\sqrt{x}^\sqrt{y}$ is actually an integer?  Or rational number?

Comment: I added the tag of number theory to the question. I do not know whether elementary number theory tag is more proper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the [Gelfond-Schneider Theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) the number is always transcendental. In particular, it cannot be rational.

Answer (score 9):

By [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), you can show that $\sqrt{x}^\sqrt{y}$ is irrational.